# How to absolute position the paragraph in pdf using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am using ASP.NET,C# and iTextSharp for creating the pdf dynamically from scratch.

I am using this.

```
Phrase ph = new Phrase(text);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph(ph);
p.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;
p.SpacingBefore = spaceBefore;
p.FirstLineIndent = 170;
p.IndentationLeft = 30;
p.IndentationRight = 50;
doc.Add(p)
```

So as you know i thought of using paragraph.spacebefore. But i need to position three paragraph in pdf and i am getting the text for the paragraphs from the user. So now based on the number of lines of the previous paragraph the next paragraph will vary with height that i don't want.

Then i thought of using this.

```
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
ct.AddText(p);
ct.SetSimpleColumn(100, 100, 500, 500);
ct.Go();
```

But in this case i want the starting point of first and second line to be different, like this

```
p.FirstLineIndent = 170;
p.IndentationLeft = 30;
p.IndentationRight = 50;
```

**Edit:**
When i try this,the properties are does not affect these paragraphs just all the lines are starting from the same point.

Is it possible?

Comment: What happens when you try that..?

Comment: Think top-left, bottom-right.. based on what you are doing If I understand you correctly ..you are overwriting the paragraph positions? you need to adjust that accordingly I would say by adjusting the first param if I understand you correctly.. so you could have to take last starting position and add like 5 or 10 to it for example..

Comment: Sorry, Can u tell me how to get the last starting position?

Comment: can you hold that in a property ..? or are you hardcoding it..10,10,10,10 then 20,10,10,10 for example..

Comment: Sorry, If i understood u correctly? you want me to set the starting position for each line of the paragraph while using that inside the columntext..can you tell me whether i understood you correctly or not?

Comment: Yes.. I have done this in the past..and it was a tedious process in regards to having to check the pdf output but you can try that and once you find a position that works for you.. then change that that to be a property(s)

Comment: Thanks. Then i am hardcoding those values so it is easy to get. Now how to set the starting position to second line.

Comment: there has to be a method for adding a new line or paragraph follow the template you already have started ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366490/how-to-add-paragraph-and-then-a-line-in-itextsharp 
look at the ITextSharp web site for examples http://simpledotnetsolutions.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/itextsharp-few-c-examples/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer it is simple. We can set the columntext property.

```
columntext.SetIndent(100, false);
```

It will add the space to only firstline.Then for linespacing I used this.

```
columntext.Leading = 31;
```

So if use the columntext for absolute position of paragraph then the paragraph property wont work. But we can use the columntext property.